# Page load is slow after authentication in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqtree

I am using Jqtree plugin to load a tree view in my mvc4 application, the view consists of a list of names sorted in alphabatical order. everything is working fine but the page load is taking lot of time.

Controller code:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController<Home, HomeModel>
    {`
        int i = 1;
        [Authorize]
        public override ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.DOM_TreeView = PopulateTreeView();
            return View();
        }

        private string PopulateTreeView()
        {
            string DOM = "";

            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            //using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 192.168.1.200; Initial Catalog=NHFP; User Id= sa; Password = server+123"))
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VMS.Demo"].ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ", connection))
                {
                    table.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
                }

                connection.Close();
            }

            DOM = GetTreeView(table);

            return DOM;
        }

        private string GetTreeView(DataTable dt)
        {
            string DOMTreeView = "";
            string[] alphabetArray = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };
            foreach (string key in alphabetArray)
            {
                DOMTreeView += CreateTreeView(dt, key);
            }
            return DOMTreeView;
        }

        private string CreateTreeView(DataTable dt, string ParentKey)
        {
            string DOMDataList = "";
            string ProviderName = "";

            var result = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(dr => dr.Field<string>("Key") == ParentKey);

            DOMDataList += "<tr class='treegrid-" + i + "'>";
            DOMDataList += "<td>" + ParentKey + "</td>";
            DOMDataList += "</tr>";
            foreach (DataRow row in result)
            {
                ProviderName = row[1].ToString();
                DOMDataList += "<tr class='treegrid-parent-" + i + "'>";
                DOMDataList += "<td>" + ProviderName + "</td>";
                DOMDataList += "</tr>";
            }
            i = i + 1;
            return DOMDataList;
        }
    }
}
```

view code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">



        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.tree').treegrid();
            $('.tree-2').treegrid({
                expanderExpandedClass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus',
                expanderCollapsedClass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus',
                autoOpen: 0
            });

            $('#tree').treegrid('collapseAll');


        });

    </script>
    <script>
        (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
            i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
            a = s.createElement(o),
                    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
            a.async = 1;
            a.src = g;
            m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-43342702-1', 'maxazan.github.io');
        ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>
</head>
<body >
    <div class="container"  >
        <br><br>

        <table class="table tree-2 table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-scrollable" style="display:block;width:25%; overflow-y:scroll;height:500px" id="tree" >

            @Html.Raw(ViewBag.DOM_TreeView)

        </table>

        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you test which part is slowing down the loading? The JavaScript? The serving of the page itself?
+ SELECT * FROM - do you really need all the data from that select query?

Comment: @TeodorKurtev  i did test it using developer tools, the serving of the page itself is slow... yes i need all the data from the select statement ...is it beacuse of the foreach loop in GetTreeView metod, is there any aleternate method for implementint it?

Comment: Use a StringBuilder when you concatenate strings. Manual concatenation of that much strings is a bottleneck.

Comment: @TeodorKurtev sure will implement it. thank you